# Send PHP mail from symfony

Tags: php, symfony, mailer

I would like to ask about how to send PHP mail() from Symfony framework, component symfony mailer.

```
"symfony/mailer": "5.0.*",
```

DSN:

```
MAILER_DSN=mail://localhost
```

Controller method:

```
public function test(): Response
{
    $transport = new EsmtpTransport('localhost');
    $mailer = new Mailer($transport);

    $username = $this->getUser()->getUsername();

    /** @var Users $user */
    $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Users::class)->findOneBy(['username' => $username]);

    if (!$user)
        return new Response("User $username not found! Email not tested.");

    $to = $user->getEmail();

    if ($to) {
            $email = new Email();
            $email->from('test@mydomain.com');
            $email->to($to);
            $email->subject('Test mail');
            $email->text('This is test mail from ... for user ' . $to);
            $mailer->send($email);

            return new Response('Mail send!');
    }

    return new Response('Mail not sent - user email information missing!');
}
```

Comment: using the php mail function is not the smartest thing, because it blocks and it sometimes happens to be *very very slow*. you probably can write your own transport for the mailer component, if you really want to use it, but the maybe you have a proper use case, why you want to use php's `mail()`? for local testing, there's fakesmtp or even the null mailer for which you can use the profiler to debug.

Comment: @Jakumi Hi, thank you very much for deeper explanation. By your recommendation is better to use smtp? If I want to use mail(), toes exist transport for this in Symfony mailer component? Thx.

Comment: it's better to use smtp. in the default symfony mailer component, there is *no* transport for php's `mail` however, there is a transport for linux `sendmail` (looked for at `/usr/bin/sendmail`. php's `mail` - as far as i know - uses some operating system command, that must be configured as well or your mails won't reach their destination either. I gather your new to this, so I would just strongly advise to use smtp. it's standardized, it's fairly easy to set up, and it has none of the downsides of mail/sendmail

Answer (score 2):

If i understant your question correctly, you want to use the new symfony mailer component to send emails

I wrote a mailService using the mailer component some time ago, maybe you can get some inspiration from it ?

```
namespace App\Service;

use App\Utils\Utils;
use Symfony\Component\Mailer\Exception\TransportExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Mailer\MailerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Email;

class MailService
{
    private $mailer;

    /**
     * MailService constructor.
     *
     * @param $mailer
     */
    public function __construct(MailerInterface $mailer)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $renderedView
     * @param string $adresse
     * @param string $subject
     *
     * @throws TransportExceptionInterface
     * here $renderedview is a a twig template i used to generate my email html
     */
    public function sendMail(string $renderedView, string $adresse, string $subject, string $env)
    {
        if ('dev' !== $env) {
            $email = (new Email())
                ->from(your@email.com)
                ->to($adresse)
                ->subject($subject)
                ->html($renderedView);

            $this->mailer->send($email);
        }
    }
}
```

You will have to configure MAILER_DSN according to your mailer parameters

( https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/mailer.html )

inside the documentation, you will find how to handle some common mailers or do the config yourself

good luck and have fun experimenting :)